# Re direct website when i click on anchor tag

Tags: php, oscommerce

Hi, I want to redirect my page to another website, I used anchor tag but when I click on this it will add my website name also
http://au.pricecomparereview.com/www.theiconic.com.au/Rococo-Textured-Mini-Skirt-113532.html

Please tell me about this . I am new in php I am using oscommerce

[www.theiconic.com.au/Rococo-Textured-Mini-Skirt-113532.html](http://www.theiconic.com.au/Rococo-Textured-Mini-Skirt-113532.html)

Comment: Post your code. Show screen.

Comment: You may be missing writing protocol (i.e. http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a PHP approach try this:

```
// Declare url variable
$url = "http://www.theiconic.com.au/Rococo-Textured-Mini-Skirt-113532.html";

// Use it to create the <a> with php
echo "<a href="$url" target="_blank">www.theiconic.com.au</a>";
```

Or with html use the PHP assing tags:

```
<a href="<?=$url ?>" target="_blank">www.theiconic.com.au</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

use like this, you may be missing http://

```
<a href="http://www.theiconic.com.au/Rococo-Textured-Mini-Skirt-113532.html" target="_blank">www.theiconic.com.au</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your anchor tag would be like this presently:

```
<a href="www.theiconic.com.au/Rococo-Textured-Mini-Skirt-113532.html" target="_blank">www.theiconic.com.au</a>
```

Change it to

```
<a href="//www.theiconic.com.au/Rococo-Textured-Mini-Skirt-113532.html" target="_blank">www.theiconic.com.au</a>
```

and it will work fine.